# Google analytics: How to make pages recrawled after URL is changed from page/xyz to page?id=xyz

Tags: google-analytics

I have an old website, which was re-implemented recently. A small portion of pages in this website had urls similar to the following:

http://example.com/page/xyz

After the re-implementation, the urls of these pages become:

http://example.com/page?id=xyz

I googled these pages and noticed that search results returned old urls. I went to Google Webmaster and followed the instructions at

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1352276?hl=en

but the search results still return old urls.

What else should I do to make search results return new urls?

Maybe this question is not Google analytics specific.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Be patient. The crawl is not instantaneous. It can take days or longer for the results to propagate.

Comment: Thanks for your info. I just hope I handled re-crawl correctly.

Comment: Yes, you handled it correctly. You can also submit an updated sitemap to Google Webmaster Tools.

Comment: AiBrean, thanks for chiming in!! Will consider it